# Django: Group by through annotate is not working properly

Tags: django, django-3.0

i am building a simple todo app and i need to group them by `status` and  `status occurence`.

i tried using:

```
instance = request.user
instance.todos.values('status').annotate(counter=Count('status'))
```

but i get this output:

```
<QuerySet [{'status': 'ON-GO', 'counter': 1}, {'status': 'ON-GO', 'counter': 1}, {'status': 'ON-GO', 'counter': 1}, {'status': 'CHECK', 'counter': 1}, {'status': 'CHECK', 'counter': 1}]>
```

i have used this method before and it gave me the results i needed but now it just does not work.

any workarounds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i forgot to `order_by`, i spent an hour trying to figure out why it's not working...

```
instance = request.user
instance.todos.values('status').order_by('status').annotate(counter=Count('status'))
```

output:

```
<QuerySet [{'status': 'CHECK', 'counter': 2}, {'status': 'ON-GO', 'counter': 3}]>
```